# neo4j use of list properties

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I have just started learning neo4j with c# client, and I'm having trouble understanding exact usage of list properies.

In the example app Im using (which runs on top of "Cineasts Movies & Actors" dataset) there is a class Actor with following properties:

```
public class Actor
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String birthplace { get; set; }
    public String birthday { get; set; }
    public String biography { get; set; }

    public List<Movie> filmography { get; set; }

    public Role playedIn(Movie movie, String role)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the class Movie as

```
public class Movie
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public List<Role> cast { get; set; }
}
```

Now, it fetches an Actor with name==`actorName` from a database as shown

```
string actorName = ".*" + actorName + ".*";

Dictionary<string, object> queryDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
queryDict.Add("actorName", actorName);

var query = new Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery("start n=node(*) where has(n.__type__) and n.__type__ =~ \".*Person\" and has(n.name) and n.name =~ {actorName} return n",
                                                queryDict, CypherResultMode.Set);

List<Actor> actors = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<Actor>(query).ToList();


foreach (Actor a in actors)
{
    MessageBox.Show(a.name);

}
```

Now Actor `a` in a sample above does have its "basic" properties (name, birthday, id,..) but the list `filmography` is null, I am unable to do the following

```
foreach (Actor a in actors)
{
    foreach (Movie m in a.filmography)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(m.title);

    }

}
```

Why to I put this List property in class declaration if it does not fetch this list of related `Movie` nodes automatically when I fetch Actor, but I must do it from a separate query?

Comment: Is this a sample app you downloaded somewhere? Or built yourself?

Comment: @TathamOddie It's from my school's very basic tutorial on neo4j subject. Is something wrong with it?

Comment: You should absolutely not be typing ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults for these types of queries. The person who taught you that is not reading the documentation, or teaching the library properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4jClient is not an ORM, and it doesn't follow relationships for you automatically. It gives you a nice way to execute Cypher queries and deserialize the results into .NET objects.

In Neo4j's model, properties can be a primitive (`boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char` or `string`), or an array of one of these primitives. They can't be whole objects.

Now, Neo4jClient doesn't magically implement the graph model for you. You need to work out how to map your model on to the graph.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out in a meanwhile that my analogy with FluentNH was completely wrong. As I said, I am new to neo4j as of this evening.
Anyway, I appreciate your effort.