# Object relational mapping with the Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Let’s consider the structure:

```
(parent) –[:HAS_CHILD]-> (child) –[:HAS_DOG]-> (dog)
```

Right now I would use the following cypher query to return a sort of hierarchy:

```
MATCH (p:Parent) -[:HAS_CHILD]-> (c:Child) -[:HAS_DOG]-> (d: Dog)
WITH p, collect(distinct(c)) as children, d
RETURN p, children, collect(distinct(d))
```

However, it would be much easier if I could have the same mapping as in the Entity Framework  (with a list of Children in the Parent class):

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I've just discovered the answer to my question: I have to implement it myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319349/neo4j-use-of-list-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of Neo4jClient as the equivalent to `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in .NET. It provides the language bindings to help you construct queries in a safe and efficient way, then retrieve the results.

It is not an ORM, like say Entity Framework.

Just like how Entity Framework uses `SqlConnection`, you could build one on top of Neo4jClient if you wanted. Somebody started one of those over here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jRepository/